# django template date formatting

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Normally the default date formats work correctly in templates, but for some reason on this project I'm having trouble getting the default date formats to work, as well as formatting the datetime in templates. I want the date times to show up as the default listed on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/, but it's showing up in this format: 2014-08-18T19:08:49.138282

Not only is the default format not working, I can't use the built-in date template filter. When I use it, nothing returns.

I'm using python 3.4 and django 1.6.5

Here is the relevant code:

```
### models.py ###
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...


### settings.py ###
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USE_L10N = True
# adding the following line doesn't do anything to change the datetime default
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'N j, Y, P'

### template.html ###
{{ post }} <!-- correctly returns the post object from the view -->
{{ post.create_date }} <!-- returns datetime, but horrible format -->
{{ post.create_date|date }} <!-- returns nothing --> 
{{ post.create_date|date:"N j, Y, P" }} <!-- returns nothing -->
```

I've looked at many SO posts regarding this topic but haven't foundthe answer. Django docs as well as prior experience indicate that everything should be working. What's missing? Any ideas?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format did you try setting the `DATE_FORMAT` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried putting DATE_FORMAT in settings.py as well

Comment: What do you mean by horrible format?

Comment: this format - 2014-08-18T19:08:49.138282

Comment: That is the default database representation of your datetime object.

Comment: @karthikr any idea why I'm not able to edit the date format? It's acting like at some point it's being converted to a string, but I can't find where/why.

Comment: I thought of quite a few options while i was commenting. None of them made sense.. Can you just try `{{ post.create_date|date:"d" }}` or something and see if it works ?

Comment: it returns nothing as stated in the question. {{ post.create_date|date }} also returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some missing information in the question. The post object was coming from a tastypie API call, and it does not treat date/datetime the same as what django ORM does by default.

I ended up switching to just use normal django ORM, but another option is the tastypie datetime can be modified with the `TASTYPIE_DATETIME_FORMATTING` setting http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/serialization.html